# "name 'c_byte' is not defined" when using import of ctypes in exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have developed a plugin-system, which is loading other files with the exec() function.

```
main_file = join(plugin_dir, folder, "main.py")
exec(open(main_file, "r").read())
```

Everything is working fine, except of the import of ctypes *c_byte* and *c_uint64*. When I use `from ctypes import c_byte, c_uint64, LittleEndianStructure` I get the error `name 'c_byte' is not defined`. Here is the class I'm defining:

```
class Data_Struct(LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("data", c_byte), ("timestamp", c_uint64)]
```

Using the same import statement in the main file, where I call the exec() function is working without an error.

Also other import statements like

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

are working correctly in the executed file.

Does someone have an idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `exec` to import files? If you need to import dynamically, use `__import__`. (Note that it is not exactly equivalent. Check the docs for how to use it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @alani for solving my problem.

I ended up using

```
main_file = f"plugins.{folder}.main"
plugin = importlib.import_module(main_file)
```

to load the plugins. I didn't get an error from ctypes now.